# How to create new level in a variable based on different rows values?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created a small toy sample to illustrate the situation: I intend to group values by Date + Persona. So for each Date - Persona, I would like to add a new level to the already existing variable Category. This new category will have associated values from the numeric features Var_1 and Var_2. The values Var_1, for instance, for this new level would come from a subtraction between the values of Var_1 for Category = "All" and Var_1 when Category = "App".

[image]

Is there a natural way of achieving this in Postgre? None of the things I considered so far are getting me anywhere. The best idea I had so far was multiplying Var_1 by (-1) for a certain level of Category and then producing a "side" table with the results of the SUM() operation populating this new level, but I don't think it will work as I imagined.

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not "variables"

Comment: thank you for the heads up.